# How to return an object base on class type?

Tags: ios, swift

This is what I need for test purposes:

```
class AssemblerMock: Assemblerable {
    func resolve<Service>(_ serviceType: Service.Type) -> Service? {
        return Service.init() //doesnt work, need to return non nil value here.
    }
}
```

Comment: What could `Service` be? It couldn't possibly be _anything_, could it?

Comment: Actually now that I thought more about it. This looks like an XY problem. You most likely do not need this method at all. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Sweeper yes it may be anything.

Comment: I am trying to mock my `Assembler` class and check if it was called under tests.

Comment: Um... Okay. Let's say I have `class Foo { init(x: Int) {} }`, and I call your method like so: `resolve(Foo.self)`. What would happen?

Comment: What does the actual assembler do?

Comment: This is Swinject approach to resolve dependencies. In your case should return `Foo` instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198490/discussion-between-sweeper-and-bartlomiej-semanczyk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with a little workaround: You need to create a protocol, let's call it `Initable`:

```
protocol Initable {
    init()
}
```

then, your resolve-Template-Method should require `Service` to be `Initable`:

```
func resolve<Service>(_ serviceType: Service.Type) -> Service where Service:Initable {
    return Service.init()
}
```

Before using it, you also need to create an extension to all the types you might want to resolve:

```
extension Int : Initable {
    // No implementation possible/needed, because `init` already exits in struct Int
}
```

and then call it:

```
let am = AssemblerMock()
let i = am.resolve(Int.self)
print (i)   // Prints "0" because this is the default Integer value
```

Remark: I made the return type to return `Service` and not `Service?`, but it doesn't matter here. If you want to support failable initializers (`init?`), you need to modify the return type as well as the `Initable` protocol:

```
protocol Initable {
    init?()
}

extension Int : Initable {} 

class FooFailing : Initable {
    required init?() {
        return nil
    }
}

class AssemblerMock {
    func resolve<Service>(_ serviceType: Service.Type) -> Service? where Service:Initable {
        return Service.init()
    }
}

let am = AssemblerMock()
let i = am.resolve(Int.self)
print (i)   // Optional(0)
let foo = am.resolve(FooFailing.self)
print (foo) // nil
```